# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"get" | "post"'

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How can I cast a value from from a `string` to a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) with jsdoc?

When I do this:

```
export default class extends Vue {
  Request (...args) {
    /** @type {'get'|'post'} */
    let method = (args.length == 2 ? args[0] : 'get').toLowerCase()
  }
}
```

I get an error saying this:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"get" | "post"'.

Can this be done without the usage of TypeScript?

Comment: The answer is in the body of the question: use TS...

Comment: @alfasin using TS implies conscequent changes in the build pipelines and seems to be an overkill for such a simple issue

Answer (score 1):

**TD;LR**

There is no support in jsDoc to inspect the content of a string.

**Longer Version**

jsDoc does a good job restricting the *type* of the variable and if you pass an object you can also inspect the types of its attributes using a combination of `@typedef` and `@param` (for more info see [here](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html)). So you can use it to check if an argument is of primitive type or if it's an object - if it has certain properties (of specified types) that's all.

If you want more than that you'll either have to implement it by yourself or use TS.